# bash script to verify rhel patching

Tags: bash, rhel, yum, rpm

we have several redhat servers which we patch from redhat satellite.

To avoid confusion, I'll use the term "host" to denote the server which is being patched.

We have a script, say, ***patch.sh***, which we'll schedule to run in all redhat hosts (virtual machine) using "Remote command" option in **Redhat satellite**.

This ***patch.sh*** script runs "***yum update***" followed by "***vmware-config-tools -d***" and ***reboot***. There's more to it, but this is just the outline.

My understanding is, "***yum update***" downloads all packages to ***/var/cache/yum/*** of the host, under various sub-directories that are named based on the channels the hosts are subscribed to, and then installs the packages and remove them from there.

Have pasted the output of command "***ls -lt /var/cache/yum***" below for better understanding.

```
[root@xyzdev01]#ls -lt /var/cache/yum
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 3 root bin  4096 Mar  1 22:27 rhel-5-64bit
drwxr-xr-x 3 root bin  4096 Mar  1 22:27 rhel-5-64bit-supplementary
drwxr-xr-x 3 root bin  4096 Mar  1 22:27 rhel-5-64bit-rhn-tools
```

Here under these directories, for example, say under **rhel-5-64bit**, there are few files along with a sub-directory called ***packages***, where packages from this channel gets downloaded to.

Per my understanding, this ***packages*** sub-directory is empty in servers where the patching is successful.

Sometimes, what happens is, the package gets downloaded to the host, but due to some intermittent connectivity issue between **Redhat satellite server** and host where patching is happening (i.e) where the ***patch.sh*** script is being run, it doesn't gets installed. But when Redhat satellite server re-establishes the connection with the host, it thinks that the host is patched and proceeds with the reboot and these servers gets listed under "Completed Systems" in Redhat satellite, whereas actually the host is not patched. Here, the package stays in the ***/var/cache/yum/channel_name/packages*** without being installed.

To avoid this corner case, we're planning to implement an additional check in the ***patch.sh*** script.

I have 2 questions.

1) Is my understanding right?

2) If yes, then if i place an additional check in the script to check for ****.rpms*** under ***/var/cache/yum*** before it actually performs the next steps (i.e) ***vmware-config-tools -d*** and ***reboot***, would it work?

Appreciate any suggestions and clarifications.

Thank you.

Comment: I would simply check the exit code of `yum update`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not scheduling updates through the satellite? If you did that then the Satellite would show you which scheduled events didn't succeed.

Comment: I've actually never seen the error you mention actually. Any time I've deployed an update its success or failure has always shown up in the Satellite (under the `Schedule` tab at the top).

Comment: Did the Script worked, And, if possible may I know the patch.sh script you are using. I'm facing exact scenario and need to create a patch script and also need to very the patching is successful or not. Thanks.